# Return matching text from textarea on keyup using jquery

Tags: jquery, grep, textarea

I have a text area that I would like to monitor for a predefined list of matching words or phrases on keyup. I can achieve this as follows but the problem I am having is displaying the matching word(s) and/or phrase(s) for the user. For example, if the user typed "test, test two", how would I return those matched items from the grep statement for display (or via some other method)? - i.e. having a div that is updated with something along the lines of "Please avoid using the following words and/or phrases: test1, test two".

```
    function isBanned(array, name){
      return $.grep(array, function(i){
        return name.indexOf(i) >= 0;
      }).length > 0;
    }

    var bannedInput = ['test1','test two'];

    $('#eventText').keyup(function(){
      var inputVal = $('#eventText').val();

      var match = isBanned(bannedInput, inputVal.toLowerCase());

      if(match){
        alert("match found"); 
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var input = $("#eventText"),
    output = $("[for=eventText]"),
    bannedInput = ["test1", "test two"];

input.on("keyup", function (e) {
    var name = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
    , match = $.grep(bannedInput, function (value) {
        return new RegExp(value).test(name)
    });
    if (!!match.length) {
        output.append(
          "<br />Please avoid using the following words and/or phrases: " 
          + "<span class=banned>\"" 
          + match.join(match.length === 1 ? " " : "\"<i>,</i> \"") 
          + "\"</span>")
    } else {
        output.empty()
    }
});
```

```js
var input = $("#eventText"),
    output = $("[for=eventText]"),
    bannedInput = ["test1", "test two"];

input.on("keyup", function (e) {
    var name = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
    , match = $.grep(bannedInput, function (value) {
        return new RegExp(value).test(name)
    });
    if (!!match.length) {
        output.append(
          "<br />Please avoid using the following words and/or phrases: " 
          + "<span class=banned>\"" 
          + match.join(match.length === 1 ? " " : "\"<i>,</i> \"") 
          + "\"</span>")
    } else {
        output.empty()
    }
});
```

```css
i {
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.banned {
    color:rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="eventText" /><output for="eventText"></output>
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. The only problem with this is that it only matches one word or phrase at a time and you can't have any other text present - e.g. "some text... test two" doesn't register.

Answer (score 0):

`$.map` may help:

```
function isBanned(bannedWords, input){
  return $.map(bannedWords, function(n, i){
    return input.indexOf(n) >= 0 ? n : 0;
  }
}
```

`isBanned` will return an array that will have entries that are either a banned word, or 0. Then you can use `$.grep` to get an array of banned words found in the input:

```
var filteredWords = isBanned(bannedInput, inputVal.toLowerCase());
var bannedWords = $.grep(filteredWords, function(n, i) {return n !== 0});
```

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing your point, but I have tried your suggestion but it never seems to return anything when I enter a banned word. Could you perhaps provide an example?